# Textbox Changes are not Reflecting in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following JavaScript function. I have two textboxes, two hiddenfields and two labels. and a button. On the click of a button I am calling this function.

On typing value in the textbox, It shows an autoCompleteList. On picking a value from this, it fetches the value from DB and fills the corresponding label. Also, at the same time it stores the corresponding selected value in hiddenfield.

Whenever one changes the value in textbox and without selecting the value from autoPopulated list, It must show the alert.

The function is working fine, If I fill a single textbox, but when I fill both, It goes to the Point A, instead of showing the alert of Point B

```
function ConfirmBox()
 {
    var txtBoxValue = document.getElementById("<%= txtFromPartNumber.ClientID %>").value;
    var txtBoxValue1 = document.getElementById("<%= txtToPartNumber.ClientID %>").value;
    var release = document.getElementById("<%= lblFromPartNumber.ClientID %>").innerText;
    var release1 = document.getElementById("<%= lblToPartNumber.ClientID %>").innerText;
    var hdnFromValueID = "<%= hdnFromReleaseNumber.ClientID %>";
    var hdnToValueID = "<%= hdnToReleaseNumber.ClientID %>";
     if ((txtBoxValue && txtBoxValue.trim() != "" && release))
     {
         if (document.getElementById(hdnFromValueID).value.trim() == txtBoxValue.trim()) 
         {
             if ((txtBoxValue1 && txtBoxValue1.trim() != "" && release1))  
             {
                 if (document.getElementById(hdnToValueID).value.trim() == txtBoxValue1.trim()) 
                 {
                    return true; //Point A
                 }
                 else
                 {// Point B
                     //alert("To Part no. has been changed. Please enter it again.");
                     var msg = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
                     msg.innerHTML = "To Part no. has been changed. Please enter it again.";
                     var myExtender = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ModalPopupExtenderAlert");
                     myExtender.show();
                     document.getElementById("<%= txtToPartNumber.ClientID %>").focus();
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             else 
             {
                 //window.alert("Please choose a Valid To Part number");
                 var msg = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
                 msg.innerHTML = "Please choose a Valid To Part number.";
                 var myExtender = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ModalPopupExtenderAlert");
                 myExtender.show();
                return false;
             }
         }
         else 
         {
             //alert("From Part no. has been changed.Please enter it again.");
             var msg = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
             msg.innerHTML = "From Part no. has been changed.Please enter it again.";
             var myExtender = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ModalPopupExtenderAlert");
             myExtender.show();
             document.getElementById("<%= txtFromPartNumber.ClientID %>").focus();
             return false;
         }
     }
     else 
     {
         //window.alert("Please choose a Valid From Part number");
         var msg = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
         msg.innerHTML = "Please choose a Valid From Part Number.";
         var myExtender = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ModalPopupExtenderAlert");
         myExtender.show();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected, when the values are matching, then return true else show them the alert. If possible can you share a working demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ or some other site, where we can replicate this issue.

Comment: Hi all, I solved the problem... It was because, I was checking the same in server method too. I replicated it only in client side and it worked.This Javascript is fine in its place.